# Drupal 8 override administration theme node form css

Tags: theming, 8

I need to override some of the styles on the Seven node form. My initial thought is to alter the form and add a custom css file. Is there a better Drupal 8 way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you only has to add some custom css form alteration will does it.

If you also have to make some changes in field templates, or some theme function alteration, I suggest you to create your custom theme, and add Seven as a base theme